# get files in order of directory path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pick files  from directory below is the format of files

```
14094901-1_SCAN_f568aecd-5f5a-424d-bb54-b2a7ee60ca9e
14094901-2_SCAN_90b3ddf3-17f9-417d-b64d-61a175a779a3
```

but when file size reach to 10 like *10* after picking files first it pics no 1 file then jumps to 10.i amusing below code don't know why it is doing do

```
string path1 = @"C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\XXXXX";
                var paths = Directory.GetFiles(path1)
            .OrderBy(path =>
                Convert.ToInt32(
                    String.Concat(
                        path.Split('-', '.')
                            .Skip(3)
                            .Take(1)
                            //.Select(num => num.PadLeft(2, '0'))
                            .ToArray())
                )
            );
```

Please let me know how can i get files in proper order 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
but getting 1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: This may help you : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22978/Implementing-the-NET-IComparer-interface-to-get-a

Comment: This code will not work as there is a conversion Convert.ToInt32 in it

Comment: ok if my understanding is wrong i dont  understand why please they just downvote ..its valid question..please read parameters to downvote a question

Answer (score 2):

This might help

```
        string path1 = @"C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\XXXXX"
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path1);
        var fileIndex = files.Select(a => new {Name = a, Index = Convert.ToInt32(a.Split(new[] {'-', '_'})[1])});
        var orderdFileNames = fileIndex.OrderBy(a => a.Index).Select(a => a.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the second split value to int before `.ToArry()`.

Comment: didnt get you ..can please write the syntax here how you are saying

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 string path1 = @"C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\XXXXX";
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path1);
        var orderedFiles = files.OrderBy(file => Convert.ToInt32(file.Split(new []{'-', '_'})[1]));
```

Comment: Are you looking at files or orderedFiles? It works in my test app.

Comment: i am looking the order even i havementioned in my question

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
var orderedFiles =  Directory.GetFiles(path1).OrderBy(path =>
               Convert.ToInt32(
                String.Concat(
                    path.Split('_','-')
                        .Skip(1).Take(1)
                       .ToArray())
            )

            );
```